# Disable Tailwind on a div or component

Tags: tailwind-css

Is there a way to [disable Tailwind's Preflight](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/preflight/#disabling-preflight) on a specific div or component? For example a WYSIWYG editor, or wanting to migrate gradually to Tailwind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as i know it will always load the ui if can find similar classes. Some solution can be

- Reducing its priority from other css, by putting it earlier from other css files in initial load.
- you can config tailwind.config.js file in a way so that it only generates css that needed
- wrapping css with extra identifier so that it can't collide with tailwind classes.

Answer (score 12):

Search about 'unreset tailwind'.

https://www.swyx.io/tailwind-unreset/

1. download file unreset.scss from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ixkaito/unreset-css/master/_unreset.scss
2. copy it over to your tailwind.scss and namespace it under an unreset class.

.unreset {   // paste unreset.scss here! }

3. And then in your JSX, you can add that unreset class in:

> div className="unreset" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: post.contents }}

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iLEYtgBezhs

Answer (score 11):

I believe the optimal method, if you're using it for basic markdown is to use the the `@tailwind/typography` package which will allow tags such as `<h6> <b>` etc...

1. run `npm i @tailwindcss/typography`
2. add `require("@tailwindcss/typography")` to your plugins in tailwind.config.js
3. add the className `prose prose-lg`

```
<div className="prose prose-lg" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: markdownDesc }} />
```

Found this method in a article here:
https://tjaddison.com/blog/2020/08/updating-to-tailwind-typography-to-style-markdown-posts/

Answer (score 5):

Another option is:

```
.element-selector {

       all: revert;
}
```

`all` can set all properties of the element to the `initial`, `inherit` or `revert` value.

More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/all